# Fragment Question, where to build buttons etc

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am using fragments to update a text view I have so when the person clicks a button the text view moves on to the next question. I'm not sure if I am doing the correct work in one fragment instead of the other. My current screen looks like this:

[image: Current Screen]

I will probably have to add some more buttons/widgets to this but should I be adding it into the XML for the fragment or the fragment container?
Here is XML for fragment actions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_question_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".FragmentActions"

    >
    <!-- this is where fragments will be shown-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/question_container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"

        android:scaleType="centerInside" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/questions_yes1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/yes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/questions_no1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="@string/no" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the fragment details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/button_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    tools:context=".FragmentDetails">

    <!--Blank Fragment Layout-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questions_text_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Updated FragmentDetails

```
public class FragmentDetails extends Fragment {


    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private List<Integer> mQuestionIds;
    private int mListIndex;



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the fragment layout
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        //Get a reference to the textView in the fragment layout
        final TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.questions_text_view1);
        if (mQuestionIds != null) {
            textView.setText(mQuestionIds.get(mListIndex));
            //Increment the position in the question lisy as long as index is less than list length
            if (mListIndex < mQuestionIds.size() - 1) {
                mListIndex++;
                setmQuestionIds(QuestionList.getQuestions());
                setmListIndex(mListIndex);
            } else {
                //end of questions reached
                textView.setText("End of questions");
            }
            //Set the text resource to display the list item at that stored index
            textView.setText(mQuestionIds.get(mListIndex));

        }
    else {
        //Log message that list is null
        Log.d(TAG, "No questions left");
    }

    //return root view
            return rootView;

}


    public void setmQuestionIds (List < Integer > mQuestionIds) {
        this.mQuestionIds = mQuestionIds;
    }

    public void setmListIndex ( int mListIndex){
        this.mListIndex = mListIndex;
    }
}
```

Fragment Actions activity

```
public class FragmentActions extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_actions);

        Button yes = findViewById(questions_yes1);

        // Only create new fragments when there is no previously saved state
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //Create Question Fragment
            final FragmentDetails fragmentDetails = new FragmentDetails();
            fragmentDetails.setmQuestionIds(QuestionList.getQuestions());


            yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

            //set the list of question Ids for the head fragent and set the position to the second question

            //Fragment manager and transaction to add this fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                  fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                         .replace(R.id.question_container1, fragmentDetails)
                            .commit();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Button`s remain the same while the `TextView` changes, you may add your `Button`s to the **fragment container**.

Remember that, your fragments will be presented inside the `FrameLayout`  of  the **fragment container**. You gotta keep your `Button`s, outside the `FrameLayout`.

Or if you want to have different `Button`s for different fragments (Questions, in your case), you can also add the `Button`s to the **fragments**. But in that case, you gotta add them separately to each of the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no **right** answer to your question. You could try different approaches.

Maybe you could implement the buttons in the fragment container, as @smmehrab pointed out. I see this as a more difficult solution, because when you click on an item from the container you can manage the views of the container, not the fragment's views. You would get NullPointer if I recall correctly. This happens because the context when the button is clicked in the fragment container is different than the context when clicking from within the fragment. So you should implement an interface on the fragment container that listens to clicks, and the fragment catches the click. You could do this, and I actually am doing it in my current app, but I have no choice.

You could instead use Motion Layout (which extends from Constraint Layout) as the root view of your fragment, instead of CardView. This way you could set all the fragment's views with a flat hierarchy (flat hierarchies improves rendering time, so that's an improvement, and you can use CardView as one child) and set the buttons right there, in the Motion Layout (remember, the motion layout would be the fragment's root view). You could set the click listener right there and implement animations between different textViews.

I'm sure there are plenty of other solutions, take this only as a contribution.

If you're unfamiliar with Motion Layout you can just google it, android official documentation about it is great.

Comment: Looks complicated enough to me a lot of animations I just want to use it to click a button!

Comment: I assumed you'd be using animations to transition from question to question

Comment: Driving me mad today trying to even get the buttons outside the fragment so I can try the interface method.  Ive updated above to show my java some variables are different from yesterday as I just started up again, maybe you can spot an error. When I click yes it displays the first question but doesnt keep going through the list

Comment: Is it possible that the XML and the code are not updated both? Because I'm seeing "question_yes" & "question_yes1". Anyways, I'm spotting an error. When you run the app, you don't get NullPointer right away? Because you're setting the listener in the activity, and in this case it should be in the fragment class

Comment: Ive updated my xml as that was from my previous attempt. I dont get a null pointer i just click the button and it does not update the question. So I should be doing my onClick in the fragement details class?

Comment: No, it's ok :) You have the button in your fragment container and you're using the listener in the Activity Class, that's ok. Have you tried using the method add() instead of replace() ?

Comment: Yeah tried that but just get a "Fragment already added" error. Really cant see the issue im sure its something small so really annoying

Comment: You should try debugging. I'd do the following. 1st: set a checkpoint inside onCreateView() to check if the fragment's getting created. If this is OK, then you have a problem with the list argument. So I'd set a checkpoint in the ".commit()" section of the activity to check if such fragment actually has a non null list. And if this is true, I'd check again if your variables aren't nulls inside the fragment. Have you done this already? Or are you new to debugging?

Comment: Log.d(TAG,"onCreateViewWorking");                                            Log.d(TAG, "Values" + fragmentDetails);                              used both of these and they both printed the values one  printed a couple of different objects with random letters.                                                                                 D/FragmentActions: ValuesFragmentDetails{a3c500b (25d56ff7-9f9c-4857-8072-9f20f320e0db) id=0x7f0a019b}

Comment: Yeah, that's because objects look like taht usually xD Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBaL78HC0ls debugging is a different thing. It allows you to watch how your program is developing line by line, and you can see exactly what's going on and where's the problem.